# Azure API Prefer: return=minimal header

Tags: azure, api, azure-active-directory, azureportal, request-headers

I came across one header called Prefer : return=minimal in Azure API delta calls, I didn’t understand what difference it makes if we use it while making a delta API call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delta query enables applications to discover newly created, updated, or deleted entities without performing a full read of the target resource with every request.
Microsoft Graph applications can use delta query to efficiently synchronize changes with a local data store.

An optional request header -  `prefer:return=minimal`  - results in the following behavior:

- If the property has changed, the new value is included in the response. This includes properties being set to null value.
- If the property has not changed, the property is not included in the response at all. (Different from the default behavior.)

> ***Example***: You are searching for changes made in users using **delta** and apply a filter `$select` to get the information of Job title, display name and mobile Number and also add `prefer:return=minimal`.
> the response you get is only display name and mobile number which means their values have been changed since the last delta query while the job title hasn't changed.

**Reference:** [Return Minimal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-delta?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#alternative-return-only-the-changed-properties)